# C++/Windows - Meaning of: system("dir \\b *.dat > tmp.txt")

Tags: c++, windows, system

I'm working on an assignment in which I have a few .dat files that I'm going to read in that corresponds to a rigid looking graph (kind of how a hear beat looks but with more data). My Prof. gave the class a specific line of code to use in order to discover all the .dat files in the current directory which is the following:

`system("dir \\b *.dat > tmp.txt");`

I understand most of what is going on within that statement, but I'm curious as to what the `"\\b"` is doing there, and if it is even necessary.

Anyone know what that `"\\b"` is doing?
Thanks world!

Comment: I think your professor made a mistake. It should probably be `system("dir /b *.dat > tmp.txt")` to get a bare listing of files matching `*.dat` in the current directory.

Comment: Figured it out with your comment as well as the comment from eryksun. It is as eryksun says, should have been `system("dir /b *.dat > tmp.txt")` so that we can get a bare listing. I'll use that bare listing to get the file names individually and the open those files to get what I need from them! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your professor made a mistake as typo:

The escaped directory path specifier will become

```
\b
```

when the `system()` call parses the command line passed as parameter.

this would list the files/directories in the current disk systems directory `b`. Say you are on `c:` this would be equivalent to call

```
> dir c:\b *.dat > tmp.txt
```

from the command line prompt.

If you meant to invoke `dir` [with the `/B` option](http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm)

> /B | Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

You just don't use backslash (`\`), but `/`

```
system("dir /b *.dat > tmp.txt");
         // ^
```

Comment: So from what you are saying, is that like saying, instead of seeing the usual C:\Users\... you would see C:\b\...  ?

Comment: Figured it out with your comment as well as the comment from eryksun. It is as eryksun says, should have been `system("dir /b *.dat > tmp.txt")` so that we can get a bare listing. I'll use that bare listing to get the file names individually and the open those files to get what I need from them! Thanks guys!